# CameraSource takePicture crashes

Tags: java, android, google-vision

I'm using play services vision: "com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2"

Application crashes regulary when i call method "takePicture" for CameraSource object

```
mCameraSource.takePicture(null, new CameraSource.PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            FileUtils.saveImage(bytes, String.valueOf(PHOTO_NAME), "png");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Log

> 08-19 17:10:38.283 30456-30456/ru.facereg.facerecognitiontest
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
>   ru.facereg.facerecognitiontest, PID: 30456 java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   takePicture failed
>       at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
>       at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1489)
>       at com.google.android.gms.vision.CameraSource.takePicture(Unknown Source:26)
>       at ru.facereg.facerecognitiontest.FaceDetectionActivity.onCreatePicture(FaceDetectionActivity.java:114)
>       at ru.facereg.facerecognitiontest.camera.GraphicOverlay.onDraw(GraphicOverlay.java:130)
>       at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19192)
>       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18142)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4220)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4200)
>       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18101)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4220)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4200)
>       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18101)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4220)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4200)
>       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18101)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4220)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4200)
>       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18101)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4220)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4200)
>       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18101)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4220)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4200)
>       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18101)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4220)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:4200)
>       at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18101)
>       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:669)
>       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:675)
>       at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:783)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2992)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2806)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2359)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
>       at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)

I tried call from work thread and from UI thread but result is similar.
Maybe somebody faced with this problem?